# Having trouble connecting apollo sql datasource with mssql; getting "Login failed for user <username>"

Tags: sql-server, apollo, knex.js, apollo-server, express-graphql

I'm trying to send GraphQL queries to a mssql database utilizing the Apollo SQL datasource. I believe the error is in the configuration object, since it's recognizing that I'm trying to access the database. I tried looking through the knex documentation (since that's the library that the Apollo SQL datasource uses) but it doesn't have that much information about MSSQL implementation. I also tried installing tedious like it says to in the documentation, but I'm not sure how I would utilize it with the configuration object. Has anybody encountered something similar when trying to send GraphQL queries to a mssql database through apollo-server-express?

```
**index.js**
const db = require('./datasources/db');
const dbConfig = {
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: {
    domain: <domain>,
    server: <server>,
    driver: <driver>,
    database: <dbname>,
    port: <port>,
    user: <user>,
    password: <pw>,
    requestTimeout: <timeout>,
    options: {
      encrypt: false,
      enableArithAbort: false
    }
  }
}
const database = new db(dbConfig);

...

async function startApolloServer() {
      const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
      const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
        plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })],
        dataSources: () => ({ database })
      });
    
      await server.start();
      
      server.applyMiddleware({ app });
    
      await new Promise(resolve => httpServer.listen({ port: httpListenerPort }, resolve));
      console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${port}${server.graphqlPath}`);

      return { server, app };
    }
    
    startApolloServer();
```

`error message: Login failed for user '<user>'.`

Comment: Are you sure the credentials are correct? Have you tried connecting to the server with those credentials using SSMS (on Windows) or Azure Data Studio (on Mac and Linux)?

Comment: I'm able to use the mssql library with the same credentials, and it sends queries just fine. Thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: Do you have access to the target SQL Server? You can check the instance's ERRORLOG file for the error 18456 message(s) and compare the State number there against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the cause of the login issue.

Comment: Yes, I have access. I'm able to access the database through DBeaver just fine as well as the mssql library, both using the same login credentials.